# Reconstruct main effect by hand taking into account interaction using a dummy column

Tags: r, lm, interaction

Let's look at the significance of `cyl` and `gear` on `mpg` in the R dataset `mtcars`.

```
car_data <- mtcars

head(car_data)

                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1

m0 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl * gear, data = car_data)

summary(m0)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl * gear, data = car_data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.8465 -2.0126  0.1848  1.4645  7.6535 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  17.1635    14.5745   1.178    0.249
cyl          -0.1794     2.0458  -0.088    0.931
gear          5.1380     3.6327   1.414    0.168
cyl:gear     -0.6720     0.5274  -1.274    0.213

Residual standard error: 3.198 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7457,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7185 
F-statistic: 27.38 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 1.786e-08
```

We can reproduce the interaction coefficient by making a dummy column

```
car_data$Ix <- car_data$cyl * car_data$gear

head(car_data)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb Ix
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 24
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 24
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 16
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 18
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 24
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 18
```

We can use the dummy column to calculate the interaction coefficient

```
m1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + gear + Ix, data = car_data)

summary(m1)
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl + gear + Ix, data = car_data)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.8465 -2.0126  0.1848  1.4645  7.6535 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  17.1635    14.5745   1.178    0.249
cyl          -0.1794     2.0458  -0.088    0.931
gear          5.1380     3.6327   1.414    0.168
Ix           -0.6720     0.5274  -1.274    0.213

Residual standard error: 3.198 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7457,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7185 
F-statistic: 27.38 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 1.786e-08
```

Although the interaction is not significant, for the sake of argument let's pretend it is. Let's imagine also, we want to know the significance of the `cyl` effect on `mpg` at a `gear` of 4. We can deduce that effect using glht and no dummy columns.

```
library(multcomp)

summary(glht(lm(mpg ~ cyl * gear, data = car_data),linfct=c("cyl + 4 * cyl:gear == 0"), test = adjusted("none")))

     Simultaneous Tests for General Linear Hypotheses

Fit: lm(formula = mpg ~ cyl * gear, data = car_data)

Linear Hypotheses:
                        Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
cyl + 4 * cyl:gear == 0  -2.8673     0.3822  -7.502 3.59e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
(Adjusted p values reported -- single-step method)
```

Is there any way to reproduce this calculation of a main effect at the level of an interaction using a dummy variable?

Many thanks